# How can I get the column number in a SWT table in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: numbers, swt, rcp

My question is How can we find the currently selected column number in the selected row of a SWT Table in Eclipse RCP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a `Listener` - e.g. for `SWT.Selection` - you can use `viewer.getCell(...)` as illustrated in the following example:

```
myTableViewer.getTable().addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        Point p = new Point(event.x, event.y);
        ViewerCell cell = myTableViewer.getCell(p);
        int columnIndex = cell.getColumnIndex();
        //...
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you nonty for your susggestion. It worked fine. Sorry to be late to accept the answer.

Comment: The question is asking about a SWT Table.  The answer is talking about some "myTableViewer" of unspecified kind, which is definitely not a SWT Table, but instead contains a SWT Table. How come this is even upvoted and accepted?

Comment: That is basically correct, but... unless you work with an SWT-only application - where JFace will not be present - you will normally always use a TableViewer in place of a bare SWT Table. The added functionality is just too big to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure that the columnindex is updated prior to calling the selectionlistener, then the mousedown event will also work fine:

```
    table.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent event) {
            try {
                Point p = new Point(event.x, event.y);
                ViewerCell cell = viewer.getCell(p);
                selectedColumn = cell.getColumnIndex();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```